# How to get the facebook users who likes a facebook page

Tags: php, facebook

I have a facebook page and its pageid. in my php based  website i have a like button plugin related to that facebook page. like button is working correctly.

But i want to get the users or their facebook user ids who liked the particular page.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In your link to the facebook site, there should be a "show_faces", set this to true and it will show all of the people who have liked your page ( or at least as many that can fit in the area you have allocated to facebook)

Comment: No, actually i want the users list(facebook user IDs) in a php variable or array.
is there any graph api or fql query that can fetch the userids ?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to get facebook users id's list, who likes your page. This is about users privacy.

Answer (score 0):

If you're a page admin, you can go to `https://www.facebook.com/browse/?type=page_fans&page_id=PAGEID` and see the list of the most recent 500.  There is no known current API feature that does this.